# Функция toggle не работает!

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть таблица которую нужно сворачивать и разворачивать по нажатию на слово "Другие города"

```
<div class="clock_another">
<div class="another">Другие города</div>
<table width="100%" id="table_country">
 <tr>
    <td id="another_country" width="45%">Лондон</td>
    <td id="tire">-</td>
    <td width="45%"> <ul>
                        <li id="hoursL"> </li>
                        <li id="point">:</li>
                        <li id="minL"> </li>
                        <li id="point">:</li>
                        <li id="secL"> </li>
           </ul>
   </td>
  </tr>
```

Вот скрипт который все делает

```
$('.another').toggle(function(){
 $('#table_country').fadeOut(1000);
}, function(){
 $('#table_country').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Но она не работает. Просто сворачивается надпись "Другие города" и все. Если вместо toggle прописываю "hover" то при наведении она исчезает. Почему не работает функция "toggle". С другими скриптами такая же проблема, "toggle" не работает.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.another').click(function(){
 $('#table_country').fadeToggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="clock_another"> <div class="another">Другие города <br> <table width="100%" id="table_country"> <tr> <td id="another_country" width="45%">Лондон</td> <td id="tire">-</td> <td width="45%"> <ul> <li id="hoursL"> </li> <li id="point">:</li> <li id="minL"> </li> <li id="point">:</li> <li id="secL"> </li> </ul> </td> </tr></div>
```

Пробуйте, и читайте хотябы что делают ф-ции, дальше сами исправить сможете?

Answer (score 0):

Довольно странно, я поставил закрывающие теги и у меня все работает. ЧЯДНТ?

```
<div class="clock_another">
<div class="another">Другие города</div>
<table width="100%" id="table_country">
 <tr>
    <td id="another_country" width="45%">Лондон</td>
    <td id="tire">-</td>
    <td width="45%"> <ul>
                        <li id="hoursL"> </li>
                        <li id="point">:</li>
                        <li id="minL"> </li>
                        <li id="point">:</li>
                        <li id="secL"> </li>
           </ul>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```